# How can I receive a message on client by socket?

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock

I'm working on a C++ project that use sockets to transfer the message, I've done the sending part which looks like this(IDK if it's correct, if no please let me know what should I do)

```
void CFinalProjectKeithDlg::OnBnClickedSend()
{

    CString ChatMessage;
    SetDlgItemText(IDC_EDIT_CHAT, ChatMessage);
    //const char* pkt = "Message to be sent";
    const char* srcIP = "127.0.0.1";
    const char* destIP = "127.0.0.1";
    sockaddr_in dest;
    sockaddr_in local;
    WSAData data;
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &data);

    local.sin_family = AF_INET;
    inet_pton(AF_INET, srcIP, &local.sin_addr.s_addr);
    local.sin_port = htons(0);

    dest.sin_family = AF_INET;
    inet_pton(AF_INET, destIP, &dest.sin_addr.s_addr);
    dest.sin_port = htons(3514);

    SOCKET s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
    bind(s, (sockaddr*)&local, sizeof(local));

    sendto(s, ChatMessage, strlen(ChatMessage), 0, (sockaddr*)&dest, sizeof(dest));

    closesocket(s);
    WSACleanup();

}
```

Now I'll need to code a receiving part that receives the message. IDK where to start, this is my first real programming project. I really don't know how to start.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you should not be calling `WSAStartup()` and `WSACleanup()` on every send.  Call them one time at program startup/exit instead.

Second, you are not doing any error handling whatsoever. Any one of those system calls could fail.

Also, you are sending a blank `CString`.  You meant to use `GetDlgItemText()` instead of `SetDlgItemText()`.

Now, that being said, to answer your question, the receive code will look similar to this sending code, except that it will need to:

- create the receiving socket before the message is sent, otherwise the message will get discarded by the OS.
- `bind()` the receiving socket to port `3514` instead of `0`
- use `recvfrom()` instead of `sendto()`

For example:

```
// client

CFinalProjectKeithDlg::CFinalProjectKeithDlg()
{
    WSAData data;
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &data) != 0)
        throw ...;
}

CFinalProjectKeithDlg::~CFinalProjectKeithDlg()
{
    WSACleanup();
}

void CFinalProjectKeithDlg::OnBnClickedSend()
{
    CString ChatMessage;
    GetDlgItemText(IDC_EDIT_CHAT, ChatMessage);

    const char* srcIP = "127.0.0.1";
    const char* destIP = "127.0.0.1";

    sockaddr_in local;
    local.sin_family = AF_INET;
    inet_pton(AF_INET, srcIP, &local.sin_addr);
    local.sin_port = htons(0);

    sockaddr_in dest;
    dest.sin_family = AF_INET;
    inet_pton(AF_INET, destIP, &dest.sin_addr);
    dest.sin_port = htons(3514);

    SOCKET s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
    if (s == INVALID_SOCKET)
        throw ...;

    if (bind(s, (sockaddr*)&local, sizeof(local)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        closesocket(s);
        throw ...;
    }

    char *msg = ChatMessage;
    if (sendto(s, msg, strlen(msg), 0, (sockaddr*)&dest, sizeof(dest)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        closesocket(s);
        throw ...;
    }

    closesocket(s);
}
```

```
// server

private:
    SOCKET s;

CFinalProjectKeithDlg::CFinalProjectKeithDlg()
{
    WSAData data;
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &data) != 0)
        throw ...;

    const char* srcIP = "127.0.0.1";

    sockaddr_in local;
    local.sin_family = AF_INET;
    inet_pton(AF_INET, srcIP, &local.sin_addr);
    local.sin_port = htons(3514);

    s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
    if (s == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        WSACleanup();
        throw ...;
    }

    if (bind(s, (sockaddr*)&local, sizeof(local)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        closesocket(s);
        WSACleanup();
        throw ...;
    }
}

CFinalProjectKeithDlg::~CFinalProjectKeithDlg()
{
    closesocket(s);
    WSACleanup();
}

void CFinalProjectKeithDlg::OnBnClickedRead()
{
    sockaddr_in from;
    int fromlen = sizeof(from);

    char msg[65536] = {};
    if (recvfrom(s, msg, sizeof(msg)-1, 0, (sockaddr*)&from, &fromlen) == SOCKET_ERROR)
        throw ...;

    SetDlgItemText(IDC_EDIT_CHAT, msg);
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer so much, but I cannot understand why you separate them into different functions like CFinalProjectKeithDlg::CFinalProjectKeithDlg(). My function is linking to the GUI that sending part is the send button in the GUI. And receiving part is a chat box that prints out what it received. ```throw ...;``` Should I implement the "..." to print out the error message? In the server part, I've no idea where to put private: Socket s;                       I'm sorry for these stupid questions, I just get familiar with sockets.

Comment: @Keith I already explained why I separated the code. I put the receiving code in a GUI button for demonstration, but in production you are more likely to use a timer or thread to call `recvfrom()` in a loop instead. Yes, you will have to implement the "..." in the `throw`s. Have you ever worked with exceptions? Why are you working with a `class` if you don't understand how it is structured and what `private` means? This has nothing to do with sockets specifically, but to OOP class design in general. Go get yourself some [decent C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/).